# SQLAlchemy relationship join between column and JSONB data

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I am trying to join a table which has a JSONB column onto another one based on keys inside the JSONB. The keys sit under the jsonb column called alert_body->relatedEntities->requests. Where each key corresponds with an ID in a request table.

This works;

```
request_rel = relationship(
        "Request",
        primaryjoin="foreign(remote(Alert.alert_body[\"relatedEntities\"][\"requests\"])).op(\"?\",is_comparison=True) (Request.request_id)",
        viewonly=True,
        uselist=True,
        lazy="joined"
    )
```

However, it does not utilise my GIN index and performs a very slow sequential scan.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gin_alert_r
ON alert USING gin
(((alert_body -> 'relatedEntities') -> 'requests'))
```

This query does utilise the index and runs very quickly.

```
select * from requests where request_id in (
select jsonb_object_keys(alert_body->'relatedEntities'->'requests') from  alert )
```

When I try and replicate this in sqlalchemy, I've done this;

```
request_rel = relationship(
        "Request", primaryjoin="Request.request_id.in_(func.jsonb_object_keys(Alert.alert_body[\"relatedEntities\"][\"requests\"]))",
        viewonly=True,
        uselist=True,        
    )
```

This results in the following error;

> Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join
> condition 'requests.request_id IN (SELECT
> jsonb_object_keys(alert.alert_body[:alert_body_1][:param_1]) AS
> jsonb_object_keys_1  FROM alert)' on relationship Alert.request_rel.
> Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or
> ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the
> foreign() annotation.

Which is exactly what I want (the SQL inside the error message), but can't seem to get it to work no matter where I use foreign() or remote().